# Iterate over pandas dataframe to create new dataframe

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate over a dataframe to create a new one.

Toy Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,5,3,6,7,0,7],[3,9,8,4,9,3,8],
                            [4,4,3,5,12,2,9],[6,3,5,2,9,1,7],[9,4,9,3,4,2,6]]),
                            columns=["time","count","apple","banana","tomato","lemon","avocado"])
```

I want to perform operations only on the columns containing fruit. Something like this:

```
fruit_list = ["apple","banana","kiwi","orange","pineapple","lemon","grapes"]
df = df[np.intersect1d(df.columns,fruit_list)]

for fruit in df.columns:
    for i,value in df[fruit].iterrows():
        x = pd.DataFrame([])
        if fruit == "lemon":
            x[fruit] = ((df.iloc[i]-df.iloc[i-1])*2)/df.time[i]*df.count[i]
        else:
            x[fruit] = (df.iloc[i]-df.iloc[i-1])/df.time[i]*df.count[i]
```

I have tried some variations of this but never get the correct dataframe output. What I want as a result is:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([["NaN",-0.185,0.313,-0.111,-0.111],
                       ["NaN",-0.74,0.063,-0.167,0.028],
                       ["NaN",0.222,-0.125,-0.111,0.056]]).T,
                       columns=["apple","banana","lemon"])
```

Comment: @Artmeis: As a general rule, if you are trying to iterate over pandas rows, your doing it wrong.

Look into using .shift(), .rolling(), .apply() or numpy.vectorize()
(Apply is actually quite -relatively- slow in my experience, which may be my fault!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for something like this. No loops needed!

Tools used:

- [select specific columns from a DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-select-specific-columns-from-a-dataframe)
- [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)
- [`DataFrame.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html#pandas.DataFrame.diff)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(
        [
            [3, 6, 7, 0, 7],
            [8, 4, 9, 3, 8],
            [3, 5, 12, 2, 9],
            [5, 2, 9, 1, 7],
            [9, 3, 4, 2, 6],
        ]
    ),
    columns=["apple", "banana", "tomato", "lemon", "avocado"],
)
fruit_set = {"apple", "banana", "kiwi", "orange", "pineapple", "lemon", "grapes"}

# Grab only the columns desired
new_df = df[list(fruit_set.intersection(df.columns))]
# Compute difference
new_df = new_df.diff()
# Double the lemon
new_df.lemon *= 2
print(new_df)
```

```
   banana  apple  lemon
0     NaN    NaN    NaN
1    -2.0    5.0    6.0
2     1.0   -5.0   -2.0
3    -3.0    2.0   -2.0
4     1.0    4.0    2.0
```

Comment: Yes that would be a perfectly simple solution. Sadly, the real dataframe and operations are more complicated. Should have clarified this more, sorry!

Comment: Your toy example should somewhat reflect the actual situation... Well, even if the operations are more complicated, the techniques here for picking a subset of columns and operating on them still stand.